# Using external modules in Visual Studio 2015 CTP6 + TypeScript 1.4

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to figure out how to import modules.
When I write a statement at the top of my .ts file such as:

```
import a = require("a");
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot compile external modules unless the '--module' flag is provided.

In previous versions of Visual Studio, there was an area with the Project's properties that allowed you to control some TypeScript configuration. Where is this located in Visual Studio 2015?

Does anyone know how I can enable importing external modules?

Answer (score 5):

Here are the steps to configure typescript per project:

1. Unload your project. If your project is based on the MVC 6 template, you will find that the `MSBuild` configuration is pretty minimal.
2. Navigate to:
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript`*

   <sub>* This assumes you installed VS in the default location.</sub>
3. Locate the `Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props` file and open it up. No need for elevated privileges, we will only be reading from it.

   It should look something like:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
     <PropertyGroup>
       <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
       <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>true</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
       <TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>false</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
       <TypeScriptModuleKind>none</TypeScriptModuleKind>
       <TypeScriptRemoveComments>false</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
       <TypeScriptOutFile></TypeScriptOutFile>
       <TypeScriptOutDir></TypeScriptOutDir>
       <TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>false</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>
       <TypeScriptSourceMap>true</TypeScriptSourceMap>
       <TypeScriptMapRoot></TypeScriptMapRoot>
       <TypeScriptSourceRoot></TypeScriptSourceRoot>
       <TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>true</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
     </PropertyGroup>
   </Project>
   ```
4. Copy the entire `PropertyGroup` element, and paste it somewhere in your `.kproj` file; it needs to be under the Project element.
5. Modify the `TypeScriptModuleKind` from none to your module definition. The options are `AMD` or `CommonJS`.
6. Save the .kproj file, and reload your project.

You should no longer get the compile-time error about including modules.

Comment: Phew, this was a tricky find, nice job. I hope they'll be making this more user-friendly in later releases.

Comment: I edited your answer to add (a lot of) formatting and some extra information as, I was not using AMD but was also getting this error. Please make sure I didn't change your intent.

Comment: I added this, but then I couldn't compile anymore with the TypeScript 1.5 Beta, stating reference to '../Scripts/file.js' could not be found.

Comment: Thank you, as well as enabling amd this also fixed vs 2015 RC not generating source maps on save for me.